# How to get lines that do not exceed 900 seconds for the last 24 hours by unixstamp

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

How to get lines that do not exceed 900 seconds for the last 24 hours by unixstamp? Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,                     // User ID
  `regdate` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',    // Registration date in UNIX timestamp 
  `lastactive` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', // Last active date in UNIX timestamp 
  `lastvisit` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  // Last visit date in UNIX timestamp
  `lastpost` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'    // Last post date in UNIX timestamp 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `regdate`, `lastactive`, `lastvisit`, `lastpost`) VALUES (13, 1569915390, 1583430726, 1583425902, 1583378778);

/*
* regdate = 1569915390 = Tuesday, October 1, 2019 7:36:30 AM
* lastactive= 1583430726 = Thursday, March 5, 2020 5:52:06 PM
* lastvisit = 1583425902 = Thursday, March 5, 2020 4:31:42 PM
* lastpost = 1583378778 = Thursday, March 5, 2020 3:26:18 AM
* 
* 1. On connection and other activity, the lastactive is updated with time ()
* 
* 2. If the session cookie is older than 900 seconds then lastvisit is updated from lastactive
* 
* 3. When disconnected, lastvisit is updated from lastactive
*/
```

Here's my query now:

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE lastvisit > (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND (NOW() - lastactive < 900)
```

**EDIT:**
I think I found with the help of @tadman

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE lastvisit < (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND lastactive < (NOW() - INTERVAL 900 SECOND)
```

Comment: MySQL really steers towards using `DATETIME` records rather than UNIX timestamp-type values. It's also a good idea to use InnoDB instead of the creaky old MyISAM legacy engine. You'll also want to use the default `INT` (`INT(11)`) instead of some quirky and arbitrary `INT(10)` value.

Comment: How would you calculate the 900 seconds value given your example row? It's not clear which of the time values you're comparing.

Comment: @tadman 900 seconds is a fixed limit value, the comparison field is lastvisit.

Comment: Still not quite clear on what that's supposed to represent. Are you saying as in `WHERE lastvisit > (NOW() - INTERVAL 900 SECOND)`?

Comment: @tadman I think like you, but it doesn't work. I also updated my question.

Comment: If you've found a solution that's great! Worth adding as a self-answer to help others in the same situation.

Comment: @tadman it is done 

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE lastvisit < (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND lastactive < (NOW() - INTERVAL 900 SECOND)
```